# My Vista's nslookup returns an ipv4 address for an ipv6 site

Tags: windows-vista, ipv6, google, nslookup

the command:

```
nslookup ipv6.google.com
```

doesn't work quite well. somtimes it returns an correct ipv6 address, sometimes it returns an ipv4 address.
How can this happen?

[im using OpenDNS]

much thanks for help.

Comment: can you add a copy/paste of the results you are seeing?

Comment: sorry MattB, it now returns correct ipv6 addresses. I only encountered this problem in some days earlier and i didn't save the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try forcing a AAAA query:

```
nslookup -type=aaaa ipv6.google.com
```

Also keep in mind that nslookup [isn't very good at what it's supposed to do](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/nslookup-flaws.html).

Comment: many thanks.So bad that nslookup is a flaw-ful tool